# Chrome on a Mac won't launch a WebDAV Word edit

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, webdav

Our company develops a Web Based .NET application and supports all the main browsers on Windows/Mac as clients. One of our features is to allow users to browser a repository of files and then "open" those files for editing in their native Office Application via WebDAV. The JavaScript command we use to launch the operation is as follows:

```
window.location.href = "ms-word:ofe|u|http://l-andhor.qvidiancorp.com/Qvidian.MVC/WebDAV/66a193fc-d742-4243-9339-a5b5157078ac/14 WFL Invoicing.docx";
```

Now, this exact URL works for all browsers, including Chrome, on Windows and Safari/Firefox on a Mac, but it does nothing in Chrome on a Mac! We get no console errors or JavaScript exceptions and I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,
Andy.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by special characters URL encoding in Chrome on Mac, which is different from other web browsers and even different from Chrome on Windows and Linux.

One option is to use the [EditDocument()](https://ajax.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.html#EditDocument) function provided with IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library. It properly forms URL to [open documents](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/open-doc-webpage/opening_ms_office_docs/) in Chrome on Mac and tested with all major web browsers on Windows, Mac and Linux.